# Wordpress: Using JavaScript to insert onclick function and img src set to change image by ID?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements

In Wordpress and Woocommerce, I am attempting to apply javascript within the child theme functions.php, so if a user clicks a specific product attribute color swatch, it will change a preview image (shown below the swatch selectors) with a specific ID to a new image source URL. I have very limited javascript knowledge and am fumbling my way through this.

I was able to get one single swatch (Black) to change the target image, but I cannot figure out how to repeat the command for the other swatches.  Here is what I have so far:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'bluetera_swatch_onclick' );


function bluetera_swatch_onclick() { ?>


    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var input = document.getElementById("ecorigidswatches_Black");
        input.onclick = function swapproductimg() {
        document.getElementById('selected-swatch').src="https://www.laserfelt.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/BlackHexagon.jpg";

}

    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Here is a link to the product page in question:

https://www.laserfelt.com/product/hexagon-acoustic-wall-tiles/

I was also trying to create a conditional statement that would only execute this function if the user was viewing a product in a specific category. But I would not figure out how to do that either.  All of my attempts failed. We have different sets of color swatches and I am trying to figure out a way to have the script load only when it is needed.

I am also wondering if this would be the most efficient way to achieve the desired result, or if there is a better way that would improve page load speeds?  I am limited to working with the existing plugin that creates these product swatch options.  That is why I am having to insert the onclick function in a roundabout way.

We do not want to use any of the pre-existing swatch plugins that only changed the main product image.

I would really appreciate some pointers, tips and direction.  Thanks!

-- UPDATE --

Based on a tweak of Michal's recommendation, I also tried this, but it did not work:

```
var black = document.getElementById("ecorigidswatches_Black");
var berry = document.getElementById("ecorigidswatches_Berry");
if (berry.checked = true) {
  document.getElementById('selected-swatch').src="https://www.laserfelt.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/BerryHexagon.jpg";
} elseif (black.checked = true) {
  document.getElementById('selected-swatch').src="https://www.laserfelt.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/BlackHexagon.jpg";
}
```

--- UPDATE - PARTIAL SOLUTION ---

With the help of Vladimir, I was able to get this to work, but if I click on any other product attribute or input, it changes the target img src to "undefined" and the image becomes broken.   Here was my working code that is in functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'bluetera_swatch_onclick' );


function bluetera_swatch_onclick() { ?>


    <script type='text/javascript'>
        
        
  
  const images = {
    'ecorigidswatches_Berry':"https://www.laserfelt.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/BerryHexagon.jpg",
    'ecorigidswatches_Black':"https://www.laserfelt.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/BlackHexagon.jpg", 
    'ecorigidswatches_Brown':"https://www.laserfelt.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/BrownHexagon.jpg"
  };
  
  //select all elements with data-color attribute
  const swatch = document.querySelectorAll('[id]'); 

  swatch.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', () => {
      let color = element.getAttribute('id');
      document.getElementById("selected-swatch").src = images[color];
    });
  });
  

    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var black = document.getElementById("ecorigidswatches_Black");
if (black.checked = true) {
  document.getElementById('selected-swatch').src="https://www.laserfelt.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/BlackHexagon.jpg";
} elseif (condition2) {
  document.getElementById('selected-swatch').src="https://www.laserfelt.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/color.jpg";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  However, I cannot get your code to do anything the way you have written it.  It does nothing when I click on the black swatch.  I did update the elseif statement to reflect the BerryHexagon.jpg image, tried adding a second var for berry and added berry.checked in place of condition2.  Still nothing.

Comment: I updated my original post to include the tweaks that I tried, based on your recommendation.  Any idea why your code would not work?

Comment: Vladimir helped me work it out.  Thank you for your assistance though!  Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

To loop the image source using an array with JavaScript:

1. Create an array that contains your image sources:
2. Whenever the user clicks the image, the changeImage() function will be called, which updates the src attribute to point to the next image in the array

```js
  const images = [
    "https://placeimg.com/170/170/nature",
    "https://placeimg.com/170/170/people", 
    "https://placeimg.com/170/170/tech"
  ];
  let currentIndex = 0;  // Keep track of which image is currently displayed

  function changeImage() {
    document.getElementById("myImage").src = images[currentIndex];
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % images.length;  // Move on to next image
  }

  // Call the changeImage function whenever the user clicks the image
  document.getElementById("myImage").addEventListener("click", changeImage);
```

```html
<img id="myImage" src="https://placeimg.com/170/170/any">
```

Edit:
Creates an object images with properties red, blue and green. It selects all elements with a `data-color` attribute and attaches a click event listener. On click, it retrieves color value from the data-color attribute and updates the image source.

```js
  const images = {
    'red':"https://placehold.co/250x250/red/red/png",
    'blue':"https://placehold.co/250x250/blue/blue/png", 
    'green':"https://placehold.co/250x250/green/green/png"
  };
  
  //select all elements with data-color attribute
  const swatch = document.querySelectorAll('[data-color]'); 

  swatch.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', () => {
      let color = element.getAttribute('data-color');
      document.getElementById("myImage").src = images[color];
    });
  });
```

```html
<img id="myImage" src="https://placehold.co/250x250/lightgray/lightgray/png">


<ul>
  <li><button data-color="red">Red</button></li>
  <li><button data-color="blue">Blue</button></li>
  <li><button data-color="green">Green</button></li>
</ul>
```

Extra:

```css
  ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none; 
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  li {
    margin-right: 10px; /* Add some space between items */
  }
  
  button {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
  }
  
  [data-color=red] {
    background-color: red;
  }
  [data-color=blue] {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  [data-color=green] {
    background-color: green;
  }
  
  .sr-only {
    position: absolute;
    left: -10000px;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    top: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <button data-color="red">
      <span class="sr-only">Red Jacket</span>
    </button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button data-color="blue">
      <span class="sr-only">Blue Jacket</span>
    </button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button data-color="green">
      <span class="sr-only">Green Jacket</span>
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you , but I'm having trouble with your suggestion also.  It seems like your method just cycles through the image list every time someone clicks on the same one swatch.  I need each swatch to change the preview image to reflect the swatch selection color.  So the Berry swatch would show a Berry colored preview image.  Brown swatch would show Brown image.  Unless I am doing something wrong or misunderstanding how your code works?

Comment: @Bluetera I updated my answer with two snippets

Comment: Thank you so much, Vladimir!  I was able to use your updated suggestion and with minor changes I got it to work.  The only changes being that I referenced 'id' as the attribute, rather than 'data-color', because that was where the plugin was injecting the color information.  I really appreciate your help!  Have an awesome day!

Comment: Looks like I have a new problem with this code. I have it implemented, but any time you attempt to change one of the other product attributes such as "Size", the image that was changed by the swatch breaks and the src is set to "undefined".

Comment: @Bluetera Can you please show me the code snippet where other product attributes such as "Size" are being changed?

Comment: I added the partially working code snippet to the end of my original post.  Is there a way to add code snippets into comments?  You can also see the code in action at the URL that I included in my original post.